# Reading through file using ifstream

Tags: c++, file, io, ifstream

I am trying to read from file:
The file is multiline and basically i need to go over each "word". Word being anything non space.

Sample input file would be:

> Sample file:
>
> test 2d
>       word 3.5
>       input
>       {
>         test 13.5 12.3
>         another {
>          testing 145.4 
>          } 
>        }

So I tried something like this:

```
ifstream inFile(fajl.c_str(), ifstream::in);

if(!inFile)
{
    cout << "Cannot open " << fajl << endl;
    exit(0);
}

string curr_str;
char curr_ch;
int curr_int;
float curr_float;

cout << "HERE\n";
inFile >> curr_str;

cout << "Read " << curr_str << endl;
```

The problem is when it reads new line it just hangs. I read everything before test 13.5
but once it reaches that line it doesnt do anything.
Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?
Any better suggestion on how to do this???

I essentially need to go through file and go one "word" (non white char) at the time.
I

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open a file 'inFile' but are reading from the 'std::cin' any particular reason?

```
/*
 * Open the file.
 */
std::ifstream   inFile(fajl.c_str());   // use input file stream don't.
                                        // Then you don't need explicitly specify
                                        // that input flag in second parameter
if (!inFile)   // Test for error.
{
    std::cerr << "Error opening file:\n";
    exit(1);
}

std::string   word;
while(inFile >> word)  // while reading a word succeeds. Note >> operator with string
{                      // Will read 1 space separated word.
    std::cout << "Word(" << word << ")\n";
}
```

Comment: typo :)
i meant to say inFile >> in question not program itself

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how "in the spirit" of the iostream library this is, but you could do it with unformatted input. Something like:

```
char tempCharacter;
std::string currentWord;
while (file.get(tempCharacter))
{
    if (tempCharacter == '\t' || tempCharacter == '\n' || tempCharacter == '\r' || tempCharacter == ' ')
    {
        std::cout << "Current Word: " << currentWord << std::endl;
        currentWord.clear();
        continue;
    }
    currentWord.push_back(tempCharacter);
}
```

Does that work?

Comment: That won't work because `istream::get` doesn't take a single `char*` as parameter and checking `!file.eof()` before performing a read doesn't always work. Also, you're comparing wide character literals to a narrow object of type `char` (those types are not compatible). I will edit it for you to get it fixed.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Thanks for fixing that up :)