# Best way to compare input values to read values from files

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to c++ programming and I have hit one of my first major snags in all of this..

I am trying to figure out how to read a value/character from a generic ".txt" file that is on notepad.  With that comparison I want to determine whether or not to read that entire line, but I can't seem to just read the single one or two digit number, I got it to read the whole line using  { 'buffername'.getline(variable, size)  }  but when I try to change the 'size' to a specific number it gives me a comparison error saying that its invalid to switch to 'int' or 'char' (depending on how I declare the variable).

Any help is appreciated.
    Thanks

Comment: If you don't reveal your program, preferrably complete, and the sample data you are working with, only a wizard with a crystal ball can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  int length = 2;
  char * buffer;    
  ifstream is;
  is.open ("test.txt", ios::binary );    

  // allocate memory:
  buffer = new char [length];

  // read 2 char
  is.read (buffer,length);

  //Compare the character and decide     

  delete[] buffer;
  return 0;
```

Comment: Okay this looks like a good solution for the code block that I am trying to work with. I will give it a shot and see if this program headache will go away finally. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an `ifstream` to get the value (*[ref 1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/)*).

Something like the following should work. Here I use a word of type std::string, but you can replace that with other types to read them (ie: int, double, etc...).

```
std::ifstream f("somefile.txt");   
std::string word;
std::string line;

if(f >> word){
    if(<the comparison>){
        line = f.getline();
    }
}
```

[Here's an extended example of how to use the ifstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619604/reading-through-file-using-ifstream)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for performance reasons it is a bad idea to read 1 byte at a time.

I suggest this alternative:

You would be better off reading in the whole line, and then using character array.

```
char variable[1000];
```

read your line in from the file into variable.

```
if (variable[1]=='c') { printf("Byte 2 (remember 0 offset) is compared for the letter c";}
```

getting a 2 digit #

```
number=((variable[3]-48)*10)+(variable[4]-48);
```

You have to subtract 48 because in ASCII the number 0 is 48.